# C# Post Request- Request.Form.Files[0] Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, http-post, c#-3.0

So, I am using postman to test this post method and its working as expected when i am posting/uploading small size file, close to 1MB, but its throwing error when uploading bigger file, 8MB+.

Line where its throwing error:-

```
await Request.Form.Files[0].CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Error:-

```
Request.Form.Files = 'Request.Form.Files' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Its a **Net Core 3.1** Application.

Adding the complete code if anyone want to replicate it.

```
    [HttpPost("File")]
    [SAPolicy(SAPolicy.Admin, SAPolicy.ConsumerApp)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile()
    {
        FileContractRequest fileContract = null;        
        try
        { 
            if (Request.ContentLength > 0)    
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await Request.Form.Files[0].CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var data = ms.ToArray();
                    var newFileContract = new FileContractRequest()
                    {
                        ContentType = Request.Form.Files[0].ContentType,
                        Name = Path.GetFileName(Request.Form.Files[0].FileName),
                        Length = data.LongLength.ToString(),
                        CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        Data = data
                    };
                    fileContract = newFileContract;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new StandardResponse<FileContractResponse>(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, null).Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        var result = await _fileService.PostFile(fileContract).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return new StandardResponse<FileContractResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, result).Result;
    }
```

I looked in to couple of different blogs and could not find anything that helps me with my problem. Any help to fix this ? what i am missing here ?

Edit 1:-
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this will help, but you can try to set your maxRequestLength setting in your web config file to more or less the size files you would want to upload.

Comment: @A.vdWalt i thought of it too, but i dont things its the problem. Current setting in we config file :- maxRequestLength="214748364"

Comment: Please share the relevant code that you are using to upload file(s), or the screenshot of the request and posted data if you do that through postman, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: @FeiHan updated with screenshot of postman